# lottie_imageAssetsFolder can't find resources in assets/images

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, lottie

I'm using lottie animation view for show after effects animation and when set

```
app:lottie_imageAssetsFolder="demo"
```

noting happened and images not showing in animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imageAssetsFolder is if your animation has actual images (which is rarely necessary).

Put your animations in **res**

> assets/animationName

or

> @raw/animationName